# Service server and client in python following tutorial does not work

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a service that I could call to change a pose of a robotic arm using MoveIt!. I follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29), but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/catkin_ws/src/robotic_arm_algorithms/scripts/set_joint_states_client.py", line 24, in <module>
    set_joint_states(joint_states)
  File "/home/linux/catkin_ws/src/robotic_arm_algorithms/scripts/set_joint_states_client.py", line 17, in set_joint_states
    resp = set_joint_states(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 435, in __call__
    return self.call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 495, in call
    service_uri = self._get_service_uri(request)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 444, in _get_service_uri
    raise TypeError("request object is not a valid request message instance")
TypeError: request object is not a valid request message instance
```

This seems as a problem purely in the client code, so I show the client code and the service definition bellow. I have defined the servise as 4 float numbers each with a specific name. So when I pass the client four numbers (via terminal arguments), I expect to be able to simply assign those values to the service message as shown below. But something is not right. Can you point out the mistake for me?

srv/SetJointStates.srv:

```
std_msgs/Float32 forearm_0
std_msgs/Float32 forearm_1
std_msgs/Float32 arm_0
std_msgs/Float32 arm_1
---
```

script/set_joint_states_client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import rospy
from robotic_arm_algorithms.srv import SetJointStates

def set_joint_states(joint_states):
    rospy.wait_for_service('set_joint_states')
    try:
        set_joint_states = rospy.ServiceProxy('set_joint_states', SetJointStates)
        msg = SetJointStates()
        msg.forearm_0 = joint_states[0]
        msg.forearm_1 = joint_states[1]
        msg.arm_0 = joint_states[2]
        msg.arm_1 = joint_states[3]
        
        resp = set_joint_states(msg)
    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 5:
        joint_states = [float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3]), float(sys.argv[4])]
        set_joint_states(joint_states)
    else:
        print("not enaugh arguments. Four arguments required: forearm 0, forearm 1, arm 0, arm 1")
        sys.exit(1)
```

---

EDIT 1

When I put `print (dir(SetJointStates))` into `set_joint_states` method of the client source code, following strings prints on terminal:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_md5sum', '_request_class', '_response_class', '_type']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322139/service-server-and-client-in-python-following-tutorial-does-not-work/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [..]
> ```

```
from robotic_arm_algorithms.srv import SetJointStates
```

> ```
> def set_joint_states(joint_states):
> ```

```
    rospy.wait_for_service('set_joint_states')
    try:
        set_joint_states = rospy.ServiceProxy('set_joint_states', SetJointStates)
        msg = SetJointStates()
        [..]
```

> Can you point out the mistake for me?

Services have a `Request` and a `Response` type. `SetJointStates` is most likely a module containing both the `Request` and `Response` types, but isn't a service request or response itself (note how the tutorial you link to imports `*`, not `AddTwoInts`).

If you'd do a `print (dir(SetJointStates))` we should be able to verify that.

In any case: you'll probably want to use the `SetJointStatesRequest`, or just use the `ServiceProxy` directly.

Another problem with the code is that you've named your `ServiceProxy` variable `set_joint_states`, while you already have a method called `set_joint_states`. That is not going to work.

---

Edit:

> When I put `print (dir(SetJointStates))` into `set_joint_states` method of the client source code, following strings prints on terminal:

> ```
> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_md5sum', '_request_class', '_response_class', '_type']
> ```

As you see, there is a `_request_class` and a `_response_class` field present.

That would seem to confirm what I wrote above (ie: `SetJointStates` is not a request or a response class itself, but the composite one encapsulating both.

As I wrote in my earlier answer, you'll want to use the `SetJointStatesRequest` class instead. Be sure to `import` that.

---

Edit 2: we should try to avoid duplicating these Q&As but I can't find one quickly, so here is an example of some code that will probably work:

```
[..]

from robotic_arm_algorithms.srv import *

def set_joint_states(joint_states):
    rospy.wait_for_service('set_joint_states')
    try:
        # bind our local service proxy
        svc_set_joint_states = rospy.ServiceProxy('set_joint_states', SetJointStates)

        # create the service request
        req = SetJointStatesRequest()

        # populate the fields of the request
        req.forearm_0 = joint_states[0]
        req.forearm_1 = joint_states[1]
        req.arm_0 = joint_states[2]
        req.arm_1 = joint_states[3]

        # invoke the service, passing it the request
        resp = scv_set_joint_states(req)

        # 'resp' is here of type 'SetJointStatesReponse'

        # perhaps do something with the response

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e

[..]
```

Note that in addition to using the `Request` class, I've also renamed the service proxy variable to `svc_set_joint_states` to avoid shadowing your `set_joint_states(..)` method.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-04-30**:
@gvdhoorn I added the output of `print (dir(SetJointStates))` into the question. I don't know what is it telling me.

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-04-30**:
@gvdhoorn Could you level down your explanation? I don't understand what are you saying. What is SetJointStatesRequest? There is no mention about such class on the internet. What am I supposed to do with it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-30**:\

> What is SetJointStatesRequest? There is no mention about such class on the internet.

`SetJointStates` is the name of your service. You defined it yourself in `srv/SetJointStates.srv`.

See [wiki/rospy/Overview/Services: Service definitions, request messages, and response messages](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Service_definitions.2C_request_messages.2C_and_response_messages) for more info on how `rospy` generates the respective classes for your `.srv`.